AWS SNS notifications in flutter to android device issue
I am able to successfully send a message to the android device however in the debug console is reads D/PushNotificationFirebaseMessagingService( 6514): Ignore intents that don't contain push notification payload and dosn't show the push notification. I am unsure what the issue is. My notification is send from a lambda function.
I have tried a few different payloads and checked different formats.. same result. Have also tried sending a test payload like this in the sns console {"GCM": "{"notification": { "body": "Sample message for Android SNS AWS", "title": "Hello world from AWS SNS" } }"} and same result
code
  const messagePayload = {
        default: 'You have a new message!', // Default message for protocols that don't have a specific payload
        aps:{ alert: {body:'test', title: 'test', sound: 'default'}}
    }
messagePayload.APNS = JSON.stringify(messagePayload);
payload = JSON.stringify(messagePayload);
    const params = {
        Message: payload,
        TargetArn: endpointArn,
        MessageStructure: 'json'
    };

